# Rollback when exiting checkout page

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, oledb

I have an ASP.NET checkout page that calls a method inside the Page_Load method

```
  private static void DecreaseStockCount(int itemID, int stockToBePurchased)
    {
        //get current stock count
        int stock = 0;
        using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle;Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=127.0.0.1)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=xe))); 
                                                          User Id=sys1;Password=admin;"))
            using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand())
            {
                cmd.Connection = conn;
                cmd.CommandText = string.Format("select stockcount from item_stock_mstr where itemid = '{0}'", itemID);

                conn.Open();

                using (OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        stock = Convert.ToInt32(reader.GetValue(0).ToString());
                    }
                }

                //if stockCount !=0, perform update to decrease stock count
                if ((stock != 0) && (stock > stockToBePurchased))
                {
                    stock = stock - stockToBePurchased;
                    cmd.CommandText = string.Format("update item_stock_mstr set stockcount = {0} where itemid = '{1}'", stock, itemID);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }

                conn.Close();
            }
    }
```

What the method does is that it decreases the stock count of my items before finalizing the checkout.

My problem is that, I cannot roll it back to the previous number/ re-update it when user exits the checkout page without finishing the checkout.

I'm stuck, please help.

Comment: You cannot guarantee to receive a signal when a user leaves your site (they can close the tab, kill the browser, lose power or internet connectivity). You need to think of a different mechanism, for example something time-based and a background job that checks for timed out checkouts. This has been discussed many times, try searching. You definitely don't want to decrease stock when someone places something in their cart, because then a malicious user can purchase all items in your shop by putting all available items into their cart. You need to work with something like "reservations".

Comment: Why not decrement your stock in the same operation as when the checkout is completed?  Then you can easily wrap this in a transaction and ensure that both are performed, or both are rolled back.  The way you have it set up now is considerably more difficult at what seems to be very little gain...

Comment: You can't really catch, if a user closes the browser. One approach could be, that you have kind of temporary decreasing, meaning if a user doesn't check out the basket within a predfined time, then the basket is cleared and the stock is increased again.

Comment: Or make a new table that represent something like `InBasket`, in which you will insert products that are in basket per user, that way you won't touch real stock count?